# Unable to run mvn install using jdk 11

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, java-11

I am migrating jenkins plugin project from java 8 to java 11. I'm facing error when I run
`mvn install`

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jenkins-ci.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:3.17:test-hpl (default-test-hpl) on project XXXX: Unsupported Java version string: `1.11`. If you use Java 9 or above, see https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223 -> [Help 1].

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>



<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>wikimedia.releases</id>
            <name>Wikimedia Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://archiva.wikimedia.org/repository/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.16</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <artifactId>gearman-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>hpi</packaging>
    <version>0.5.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Gearman Plugin</name>
    <description>Integrates Gearman application framework with Jenkins</description>
    <url>https://plugins.jenkins.io/gearman-plugin/</url>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>zaro0508</id>
            <name>Khai Do</name>
            <email>zaro0508@gmail.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>hashar</id>
            <name>Antoine Musso</name>
            <email>hashar@free.fr</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:jenkinsci/gearman-plugin.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:jenkinsci/gearman-plugin.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/jenkinsci/gearman-plugin</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <java.level>11</java.level>
        <jenkins.version>2.277.1</jenkins.version>
        <gson.version>2.8.2</gson.version>
        <gearman.version>0.10</gearman.version>
        <hamcrest.version>2.2</hamcrest.version>
        <mockito.version>2.28.2</mockito.version>
        <powermock.version>2.0.7</powermock.version>
        <objenesis.version>3.0.1</objenesis.version>
        <jenkins-maven-plugin>3.8</jenkins-maven-plugin>
        <slf4j-api>1.7.30</slf4j-api>
        <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
        <findbugs.failOnError>false</findbugs.failOnError>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jenkins.tools.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom-2.235.x</artifactId>
                <version>25</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jenkins</groupId>
            <artifactId>configuration-as-code</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jenkins.configuration-as-code</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-harness</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jenkins-test-harness</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wikimedia.gearman</groupId>
            <artifactId>gearman-java</artifactId>
            <version>${gearman.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!--
                    Jenkins brings slf4j-over-slf4j which does the opposite
                    of slf4j-log4j12.
                    https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop
                -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>${objenesis.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jenkins-maven-plugin}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-job</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>structs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-cps</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.11.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-providers-standard</artifactId>
                        <version>1.11.2</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                        <release>11</release> 
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: could you execute your command with `-X` and share  - (1) stack trace with the same error but more relevant traces (2) configuration for maven, java, etc from the execution... further if possible a minimal reproducible example is what is expected at SO to expedite things.

Comment: random tweak, try adding [`java.specification.version`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-hpi-plugin#30-2018-12-05) to properties...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-hpi-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-hpi</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>hpi</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/jenkins</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <minimumJavaVersion>11</minimumJavaVersion>
                <systemProperties>
                    <hudson.Main.development>true</hudson.Main.development>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-insert-test</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>insert-test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/jenkins</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <minimumJavaVersion>11</minimumJavaVersion>
                <systemProperties>
                    <hudson.Main.development>true</hudson.Main.development>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-test-hpl</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-hpl</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/jenkins</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <minimumJavaVersion>11</minimumJavaVersion>
                <systemProperties>
                    <hudson.Main.development>true</hudson.Main.development>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-resolve-test-dependencies</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>resolve-test-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/jenkins</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <minimumJavaVersion>11</minimumJavaVersion>
                <systemProperties>
                    <hudson.Main.development>true</hudson.Main.development>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-validate</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>validate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/jenkins</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <minimumJavaVersion>11</minimumJavaVersion>
                <systemProperties>
                    <hudson.Main.development>true</hudson.Main.development>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <minimumJavaVersion>11</minimumJavaVersion>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/jenkins</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <systemProperties>
                    <hudson.Main.development>true</hudson.Main.development>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

By overriding the complete hpi plugin dependency I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have done something like:

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.11</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.11</maven.compiler.target>
```

change it to:

```
<maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
```

1.8 was acceptable for Java 8 but you need 11 now.

Based on your comment, your compiler plugin should look like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>11</release>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

3.8.1 is the newest version of the compiler plugin.

Comment: I've used <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>11</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                        <release>11</release> 
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>.

Comment: The error message suggests that the plugin with the problem is `maven-hpi-plugin` which takes a version number as the `minimumJavaVersion` parameter. Make sure that one also uses `11`.

Comment: No luck even in below code.     <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-hpi-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.17</version>
          <configuration>
                <minimumJavaVersion>11</minimumJavaVersion>
              </configuration>
        </plugin>

Comment: @stdunbar, I'm facing the same error after implementing your change.

Comment: @Geeky - can you post your `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the plugin section of build worked for me:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-hpi-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <loggers>
            <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch>FINE</org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch>
        </loggers>
        <minimumJavaVersion>1.8</minimumJavaVersion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

You could probably remove the <loggers> section.